# MinervaNeue not loading text formatting

Tags: mediawiki

The MinervaNeue skin on my MediaWiki installation is not loading the text formatting of the wiki. The attached image is an example:

[image: MinervaNeue Mobile Layout]

The Vector skin doesn't give me any issues (but it isn't mobile-friendly, either). Does anyone have a solution for this?

**Edit:** Here is the part of LocalSettings.php where I load and apply the skin:

```
wfLoadSkin( 'MinervaNeue' );
wfLoadExtension( 'MobileFrontend' );
$wgMFAutodetectMobileView = true;
$wgMFDefaultSkinClass= "SkinMinerva";
```

Comment: FWIW very recent versions of Vector are responsive (although nowhere as nice on mobile as Minerva).

Answer (score 0):

[ResourceLoader](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader) CSS modules have a target property; the target must include `mobile` to be loaded on mobile devices. E.g. [this is how Vector does it](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-skins-Vector/blob/master/skin.json#L42).

Presumably whatever source your text formatting styling comes from omits to do that.